# How to change the control template effectively in WPF?

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

The subject is that I've defined a customized control bound to a DataContext. And I wished to change the control template dynamically according to the DataContext's specific property values.

There're 2 ways I've thought of,but I have no idea about which way is better.

1.Do not use the control template in a ResourceDictionary and all details of the control are defined in C# code.Use the DependencyProperty CallBack method to render the control when DataContext's property values change.

2.Define control template in the ResourceDictionary and use DataTrigger to change the 'Control.Template' property.

In my application,thousands of instances in this type would be created,so it's really unacceptable if the ControlTemplate changging is not effective.

Could you please give me some advices or better solutions?

Comment: is it required to change the template once it has been rendered? so property value changes after the control is loaded?

Comment: The tamplate should be changed when the property value is changing.For example,the property 'Shape' may has diverse  values ,such as 'Triangle''Rectangle''Circle' and so on and the template should be changed when the value is changing.  @Martin Moser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any standard WPF technique might not be effective if it would involve a thousands of instances of complex controls. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483292.aspx.

I would go with MultiBinding + IMultiValueConverter to Control.Template dependency property, since Template would depend on multiple DataContext properties and would, perhaps, involve complex logic.

Comment: Thanks!The article above is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could used a `ContentPresenter` in your `ControlTemplate` to customize parts of your control. You could provide `DataTemplate`s for those customizable parts which are automatically applied.

Comment: Thanks!But I want to find which way is better,especially the efficiency must be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a style with the data triggers to control which template is displayed. Like this example:

```
<Style x:Key="Die1Face" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource dieNone}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ThrowDie1[0]}" Value="1" >
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource dieOneA}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ThrowDie1[0]}" Value="2" >
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource dieTwoA}" />
            </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

This would give the flexibility you need.